# Rails - How to query M2M fields

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Tl;dr: How can I say Rails get me all books where the title contains search_term or the name of one of the authors contains the serach_term.

I have Author and Book models. Author has many books and book has many authors.
Book has title and Author has first name.
I would like to have a search method in Book model that says something like this:

```
class Book < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :reviews
    has_many :rates
    has_and_belongs_to_many :authors, class_name: "Author"
    has_and_belongs_to_many :genres, class_name: "Genre"

    def self.search(search_term)
        where("title LIKE ?", "%#{search_term}%").or(where('first_name LIKE ?', "%#{search_term}%"))
    end
end
```

Here is the Author model just in case:

```
class Author < ApplicationRecord
      has_and_belongs_to_many :books
end
```

First of all `author.first_name` is not correct because that field is M2M so named as "authors" and the value for that field is a queryset.
Long story short: How can I say Rails get me all books where the title contains search_term or the name of one of the authors contains the serach_term. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Have you looked at [the Guide under joining tables](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#joining-tables)? It seems like this is pretty much covered there.